# Toggle div states won't work on self clicks

Tags: jquery

What I want: to have a divs toggle between show/hide associated divs on click. This would include if I click on a link and then re-click same link it should toggle states.

What I am using

```
function toggleVisibility(newSection) {
    $(".section").not("#" + newSection).hide();
    $("#" + newSection).show();
}
```

```html
<div id="navigation">
    <ul id="navbar">
        <li><a id="home" class="active" href="#"><span></span>Home</a></li>
        <li><a id="depot" onclick="toggleVisibility('depots_panel');" href="#"><span></span>Depot</a></li>
        <li><a id="reports" onclick="toggleVisibility('reports_panel');"><span></span>Reports</a></li>
        <li><a id="admin"><span></span>Admin</a></li>   
        <li><a id="logout" href="#" onclick="logOut();"><span ></span>Log Out</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Currently when I click between links the divs will toggle between each other but nothing I've tried seems to make a link toggle when it's self clicked. It's probably simple and I just can't see it. Any help would be MOST appreciated!

Comment: It doesn't work because your function logic is simply telling the target of your click to `show` and everything else to `hide`.  Also, with jQuery you do not need all that inline JavaScript.

Comment: Do you want both of them to be visible at a given time?

Comment: only 1 at a time should be visible. and when I re-click it should toggle...ex: If I click on depot, the depot div shows. If I click again it hides.

Comment: @Sparky what do you suggest for a change?

Answer (score 0):

#### Instead can you do this way?

```
function toggleVisibility(newSection) {
    $(".section").hide();
    $(".section#" + newSection).show();
}
```

#### Or something like:

```
function toggleVisibility(newSection) {
    $(".section").hide(0, function() {
        $(".section#" + newSection).show();
    });
}
```

Comment: so should each section have a unique ID because what that appears to do is overlay the div with a new one until you self click

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://api.jquery.com/toggle/ method

```
function toggleVisibility(newSection) {
    $("#" + newSection).toggle();
}
```

Comment: so should each section have a unique ID because what that appears to do is overlay the div with a new one until you self click